# lighttpd download prompt when attempting to execute python cgi

Tags: python, lighttpd

I'm using lighttpd 1.4.45 on Ubuntu 18LTS in a virtual machine. I have enabled the cgi module, set the assign to python (I also tried the usual ^/cgi-bin/), and added ".py" to the static file exclusion list.

My problem is that, despite seemingly correctly configuring python as my CGI interpreter, lighttpd still seems to refer to .py files as static files. Loading a python file in any directory (including cgi-bin) results in a prompt to download the file. Firefox was used for testing.

My lighttpd.conf:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_compress",
     "mod_redirect",
    "mod_cgi",
)

server.document-root        = "/home/william/Desktop/Space.io/" 
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log" 
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid" 
server.username             = "www-data" 
server.groupname            = "www-data" 
server.port                 = 80

index-file.names            = ( "index.py", "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".py", ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/" 
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
## Use ipv6 if available
#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl" 
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

My 10-cgi.conf:

```
# /usr/share/doc/lighttpd/cgi.txt

server.modules += ( "mod_cgi" )

cgi.assign    = ( ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl",
                  ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python" )

#$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin/" {
    #cgi.assign = ( "" => "" )
#}

## Warning this represents a security risk, as it allow to execute any file
## with a .pl/.py even outside of /usr/lib/cgi-bin.
#
#cgi.assign      = (
#    ".pl"  => "/usr/bin/perl",
#    ".py"  => "/usr/bin/python",
#)
```

Why is this happening? How can I correctly configure lighttpd to execute python files?

Answer (score 0):

cross-posted and answered at https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/8074

lighttpd is working correctly.  Your browser is prompting you to save a file since the response from the python code did not contain a Content-Type response header indicating the content type (e.g. text/html or text/plain)